# Why doesn't iText add tables which are near the page bottom to the document?

Tags: java, c#, pdf, itext

I have a lot of small tables, which i encapsulate in a sorrounding 1x1 table, and set the SplitRows attribute to false on the sorrounding table. This way, i can avoid my table getting split when it reaches the bottom of a page. When i get to the end of a page, and there is a little space for text, but not enough for the next table, iText doesn't add the table at all, but continues to add the next table in the list.

If there is not enough space for the table on the current page, id like to send it to the next. What can i do?

http://compgroups.net/comp.text.pdf/Avoid-page-breaks-in-PdfPTable-using-iText-1.2

This is my code:

```
public static void CreateMatrixProcentQuestionTable(ShowQuestionViewModel model, Document doc)
    {
        ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel sm = (ShowMatrixQuestionViewModel)model;

        Font fontsize = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 9f);
        Font QuestionFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12f);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(sm.columns.Count + 2);

        // Tilføj spørgsmålet i en række for sig selv, ellers er der chance for at 
        // svarmulighederne ikke kommer med ved page breaks
        PdfPCell question = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(sm.Question_Wording + Environment.NewLine, QuestionFont));
        question.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        question.Colspan = table.NumberOfColumns;
        table.AddCell(question);

        // Tilføj et mellemrum mellem spørgsmålet og svarmulighederne
        PdfPCell mellemrum = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
        mellemrum.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        mellemrum.Colspan = table.NumberOfColumns;
        table.AddCell(mellemrum);

        // Tilføj rækker og kolonner 

        // Dette er den første tomme celle
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", fontsize)));

        foreach (MatrixColumns column in sm.columns)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.Column_Description, fontsize));
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }

        PdfPCell ialt = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("I alt", fontsize));
        ialt.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        table.AddCell(ialt);


        foreach (var pair in sm.columnrow)
        {
            MatrixRows row = pair.Key;

            PdfPCell rowcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Row_Description == null ? "*" : row.Row_Description, fontsize));
            rowcell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

            table.AddCell(rowcell);

            foreach (MatrixColumns column in pair.Value)
            {
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("%", fontsize));
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }

            PdfPCell sumcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("100%", fontsize));
            sumcell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            table.AddCell(sumcell);

        }

        // Man laver en 1x1 table uden om den rigtige table, og sætter 
        // SplitRows = False. Dette gør at tabellen ikke bliver knækket over 
        // ved page breaks

        PdfPTable sorroundingTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        PdfPCell innerTable = new PdfPCell(table);

        innerTable.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        sorroundingTable.AddCell(innerTable);

        sorroundingTable.SplitRows = false;

        doc.Add(sorroundingTable);
        doc.Add(new Phrase(Environment.NewLine));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
table.setKeepTogether(true)
document.add(table)
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer.  This will remove the question from the unanswered list.  Thanks.